# Is it possible to ask docker login before deleting the containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

We are using multiple `docker containers` in the office system, this system can be handled by anyone as an administrator, how to prevent deleting of containers or images from the users?

Is it possible to ask the docker login before deleting the containers?

These features required for `Mac`, `Windows`, and `Linux` Platforms.

Comment: is this linux or windows based?

Comment: @james, actually I asked for all platforms, like Mac, Windows and Linux